# java : Not able to open finder window having space in path

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I want to open finder window on clicking of a button and highlight a particular file in javafx but finder window is not getting open for the folder which contains space in its name.
Code snipped for the same is:-

```
@FXML
    public void openFolder(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            String upperCaseOperatingSystem=MCOBillingAppUtils.getOSName();
            String path=lblPath.getText();
            if(upperCaseOperatingSystem.contains("WINDOW")){
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select,"+path);
            }else if(upperCaseOperatingSystem.contains("MAC")){
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -R "+path);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            DialogMessageClass.infoBox("Something went Wrong. Please try again sometimes.", "Error");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            DialogMessageClass.infoBox("Something went Wrong. Please try again sometimes.", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Path is: 
/ME/Development Folder/Short_Closed/abc.pdf

Tried path values are:-
/ME/Development Folder/Short_Closed/abc.pdf

/ME/Development\ Folder/Short_Closed/abc.pdf (Putting backslash with space)

Comment: Try wrapping the path in quotes, i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -R \""+path+"\"")`

Comment: @James_D Tried but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried running exactly the same thing from a terminal?

Comment: @James_D From Terminal it is getting open. My apporach is also working fine from terminal after putting backslash with space.

Comment: Print out the actual string you are passing to `exec` and see what is different from the command that works in terminal.

Comment: @James_D It is printing string as ' open -R "/ME/Development Folder/Short_Closed/4545cvcvcvcv_Q.pdf" ' when the same string i am copying and pasting to terminal it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mac (and probably windows too), use the longer form of [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-):

```
// note no leading forward slash
String file = "ME/Development Folder/Short_Closed/abc.pdf"
File workingDir = new File("/");
String[] cmd = new String[]{"open", "-R", file};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, workingDir);
```

You can break up the working directory and file you want to open in any way you need. E.g.

```
// Note leading forward slash:
File file = new File("/ME/Development Folder/Short_Closed/abc.pdf") ;
File workingDir = file.getParentFile();
String filename = file.getName();

String[] cmd = new String[] {"open", "-R", filename} ;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, workingDir);
```

will also work